# how to set xtrapivotgrid datasource from dataset dynamically at run time

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I have an application where user can select tables to be populated , i create the XtraPivotGrid at the runtime when I bind its datasource to dataset returned from function no thing appear , can anyone help me, thank you .

```
DataSet database = function();

DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.PivotGridControl pivotGrid = new DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.PivotGridControl();

pivotGrid.DataSource = database;

pivotGrid.RetrieveFields();
pivotGrid.ForceInitialize();
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also add the created PivotGrid to the form:

```
DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.PivotGridControl pivotGrid = new DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.PivotGridControl();

Controls.Add(pivotGrid);
pivotGrid.ForceInitialize();
pivotGrid.DataSource = database.Tables[0];
pivotGrid.RetrieveFields();
```